# Pasting Word text into utf-8 HTML file

Tags: html, character-encoding, ms-word

**Background:** I create a lot of broadcast e-mails at my job, and the content for these e-mails are usually sent to me in a Word document. I hand-code my e-mails with an XHTML 1.0 Transitional doctype and UTF-8 character set.

**My question:** What's the fastest way to convert text copied from MS Word to UTF-8 so I can paste it into my XHTML files?

**For now...** I created my own character encoding converter in Coldfusion, but it's very rudimentary and handles "problem characters" only if I specify them and only one at a time. Example:

```
function HTMLEncode(string) {
   string = Replace(string, '&', '&amp;', 'ALL');
   string = Replace(string, '©', '&copy;', 'ALL');
   string = Replace(string, '—', '-', 'ALL');
   ...
```

There has to be a better/simpler/faster way. Any suggestions?

Comment: If it wasn't clear from my question: I know very little about how character sets are handled between applications and documents. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try notepad++. There is a plugin called TextFX that might do this for you. If not, there are a lot of plugins available for it so chances are you might find one.

Here is the link for [notepad++ plugins](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So far I haven't gotten Notepad++ to _convert_ my problem characters to a utf-8 counterpart, but it's at least much easier to see where they are.